# Flutter - Firebase - Query by list item value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of availabilities and would like to query based on the value of, for example, key 31, being > 0.  I haven't found the correct syntax to make it happen.  I'm getting

```
flutter: Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.
```

Is there a way to get this working? Or do I need to rethink the query?

```
final Query nextSlot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('locations')
        .where('availability{31}', isGreaterThan: 0);

..does not give error but gives 0 results..

        .where('availability[31]', isGreaterThan: 0);
        .where('availability/31', isGreaterThan: 0);
.. returns the format error.
```

Happy new year and thanks!

[image: firestore]

Comment: You don't actually have a list type field here - you have a map whose keys are numbers in the form of strings (all map keys are always treated as strings, even if they look like numbers).  You can use dot notation to filter a query based on the values of map fields.

Comment: tried everything but a dot. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure firebase and Dart use the dot notation so you'd need this:

```
final Query nextSlot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('locations')
        .where('availability.31', isGreaterThan: 0);
```